# How to change roundings for MonetaryAmount division in jsr-354

Tags: java, java-money, jsr354

I use `jsr-354` `org.javamoney.moneta` api for Currency.

I need to divide money, for example I want set roundings to 0.25

So 100 dollars / 3 should be 33.25

By default

```
 val dollar100 = FastMoney.of(100, Monetary.getCurrency(Locale.US))  
 val res = dollar100.divide(3)
```

result is 33.3333

Is there a build in way to set roundings for that, or maybe other solutions?

Comment: As long as the computation for currency conversion is correct, you might get an extraneously long float, but is there a reason you can't just round it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think The JSR 354 RIs (Moneta / Moneta-BP) provide that out of the box, but you can certainly define your own `MonetaryRounding` for such case. If it makes sense for a large number of users, we'd be happy to consider it for JavaMoney-Lib or Shelter.